# Identify zeroes of circuit by inspection

Tags: frequency-response, pole-zeroplot

In a circuit, we can approximate the poles of the transfer function by calculating the AC Resistance and Capacitance at every node. For every node we get a pole so a change of slope in the Bode plot by -20db/dec. Is there a similar way of approximating the zeroes of the transfer function, so we get a clearer picture of the circuits frequency response?

Comment: Just look for notch filters and high pass filters in the schematic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inspecting a circuit to determine if there are zeroes is part of the *fast analytical circuits techniques* or FACTs as described in [my book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) on the subject.

The first thing is to place each energy-storing element in its high-frequency state and check if the *stimulus* can propagate through the circuit to form a *response* on the output. See the circuit below:

[image]

If you place \$L_1\$ in its high-frequency state (open-circuit it) while \$C_2\$ is kept in its dc state (open-circuited), you see that if you apply a stimulus at \$V_{in}\$ then you can follow the signal which through \$R_2\$ finds its way to the output node: you have response if you open-circuit \$L_1\$. It means that this element contributes a zero in the transfer function. Now, place \$C_2\$ i its high-frequency state (short-circuit it) and check if the stimulus still makes it to the output while \$L_1\$ is back in its dc state (a short circuit). Yes, you have a response then a second zero.

Now, where are these zeroes located? To find where they are, you have to find the impedance condition in the circuit where, for a certain stimulus frequency, you *null* the response. In other words, for a given frequency - the frequency of the zero you want - , the stimulus is blocked somewhere in the circuit. Either a series impedance becomes an infinite value or a branch is shunted to ground. In the below circuit, when \$Z_1\$ approaches infinity, the stimulus is lost and when \$Z_2\$ becomes a *transformed* short, there is no current in \$R_4\$ and the output is nulled. Both of these conditions reveal where the zeroes are located:

[image]

Once you have solved simple equations - in your mind with some habit - the numerator of the transfer functions comes up immediately in a factored form. When you acquire the skill to run these manipulations in your mind, then the determination of the transfer function becomes lightning-fast - *comme l'éclair* : )

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I will definitely check out your book in the future .

Comment: Glad if you like the answer! You can also check my [APEC 2016](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) seminar on the subject.

Comment: @VerbalKint,The APEC 2016 link is not working I think.Did not get any material

Comment: @Hari, sorry, forced-change of internet provider recently. The PPT is [here](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf), thank you.